# Cannot list users - ERROR running force:user:list: Must pass a username and/or OAuth options when creating an AuthInfo instance

Tags: salesforcedx, oauth

When I run `sfdx force:user:list` this is the error message I get:

ERROR running force:user:list:  Must pass a username and/or OAuth options when creating an AuthInfo instance.

This issue came up after setting up Travis. Travis is able to create users but I'm not.

EDIT: I get this error message also for trying to create a user and trying to look at a deployment report.

Answer (score 1):

This error generally occurs when the SFDX command doesn't include an org to look at. You probably need to change the command to be

```
sfdx force:user:list -u OrgAlias
```

Comment: when I did that this is the error message I got:
ERROR running force:org:list:  Unexpected arguments: -u, DevHub
See more help with --help

Comment: You would need to make the above change if you were running `force:user:list`, with `force:org:list` you are just looking at all of the orgs you have set up with SFDX.If you use the command `sfdx force:org:list` you should be able to see all of your orgs and their respective aliases. Then you can pick which on you want to use as the org alias for the `sfdx force:user:list` command.